# How to access Heroku from command line if directory has been deleted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

A little while ago the files on my Macbook Pro were deleted by Apple, including a directory from which I used to access Heroku and be able to do command line operations in the Ruby/Rails console.  Now that the directory is gone, I'm not sure if it's possible to access this repository from the command line, which I need to do to reduce the size of my database to stay within Heroku limits.

**Update**

before the directory was deleted on my mac, I used to simply cd into that directory and then run something like bundle exec heroku run console or heroku run bundle exec console, anyways if I did it from that directory heroku knew which application i was trying to access and it would take me into the rails console for it (where I could manipulate data)

Comment: When you say "I'm not sure if it's possible to access this repository" do you mean you've tried and you can't access it?  Also, how did you log in before?  Was it via ssh or by username & password?

Comment: Can you still access your Heroku account? If you can get on there then you can grab a new toolbelt link to install via the CLI for your creds I believe.

Comment: @maxwilliams before the directory was deleted on my mac, I used to simply `cd` into that directory and then run something like `bundle exec heroku run console` or `heroku run bundle exec console`, anyways if I did it from that directory heroku knew which application i was trying to access and it would take me into the rails console for it (where I could manipulate data)

Comment: @AlexLynham but since I have a few different applications on heroku, I'm not sure how to indicate which one I'm trying to access. As I mentioned in my comment just above this one, if I ran the console command from within the directory of my rails app, heroku knew which one I was trying to communicate with and connected me to that specific console

Comment: See my answer below. Heroku can give you a Heroku git address for your app, which you can then add on a per-directory basis pretty easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Install the Heroku toolbelt (it's unclear whether you still have that)
- From the terminal, perform a `heroku login` to authenticate
- From a directory where you want the new app to live, run `heroku git:clone APP-NAME`

You'll now have a directory, which will have the latest files you pushed to Heroku - which will allow you to do things like `git push heroku master`, or `heroku run rails console`.

You probably want to then also attach your git repo where you are storing your source code with something like `git remote add origin git@github.com:whoyouare/app-name.git`

Comment: Thanks, your answer seems like it would work but I ran into an extra problem trying to make it work. I believe some of the security credentials on my computer were changed, and I got this error from heroku. any suggestions? `Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '50.19.xx.xxx' to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.`

Comment: Looks like you may need to generate and add new keys. See the doc on [keys](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys)

Answer (score 0):

From the Heroku docs:

You can also take an existing Git repo and add a remote using the git URL provided when you created your app. You may need to do this to associate a Git repo with an existing application. The heroku git:remote command will add this remote for you based on your applications git url.

```
$ heroku git:remote -a falling-wind-1624
```

This will add your Heroku repo with the remote name of `heroku` to your working directory.